# To have someone's brow

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

What does the expression mean? I've heard it multiple times, but never grasped its meaning. Does it mean to have the same eyebrows? Or the same eyes or face expression?

Example:
"She has her father's brow."

Comment: A persons' [brow](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brow) is their forehead -- specifically the skin between their hair line and eyebrows. I understand your phrase to mean that the person has the similar pattern of creases on their forehead as her father.

Comment: I don't think it's an idiom in American English,  as compared  to *to have someone's ear*. To me, "She has her father's brow" means "She gets her brow (more) from her father than her mother" or "The shape, size, color, etc of her brow (much) more resembles that of her father as compared to that of her mother.

Comment: I last read this in a book - Assassin's Quest by Robin Hobb - where someone said to a newborn: "You're going to have Chivalry's brow".

Comment: Is that the usage you really want to ask about? Then I would edit your question and put that line in there and include the name of the book and a link to it [such as this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=-T0cz9BZ_DcC&pg=PA219&lpg=PA219&dq=You%27re+going+to+have+Chivalry%27s+brow&source=bl&ots=Ov1zYNyAiS&sig=N2KuhuDJOV0bbnSSlqg-52lJph8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb7OOx-ffWAhUiw4MKHTW8AKUQ6AEIdDAV#v=onepage&q=You're%20going%20to%20have%20Chivalry's%20brow&f=false). You should say whether Chivalry is the name of someone or the abstract quality (like Lady Liberty).

Comment: At any rate, it's seems a metaphorical use of the same thing I was saying,since the context is looking at a baby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it refers to the more extended meaning of ***[brow](http://www.yourdictionary.com/brow)*** (literary)

> - a facial expression: *her troubled brow*

(M-W)

Comment: I agree. The facial expression of the brow reveals trouble within and some display it more than others. Dispositions within can be inherited and so can the propensity to display them facially.